# Select tag doesn't work properly when container has css3 transform in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css

I have an issue where I want to animate my container boxes using css3 transform, which contains content such as a select dropbox. The issue is that in Firefox 16.0.2 the select function doesn't work. It's very glitchy. Remove the transform and it works fine.

Any possible work arounds without resorting to jquery animate?

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/DZjPr/

Sorry! I had the jfiddle all ready but forgot to add the link

```
 <div id="container" style="transform: translate(0px, 17px); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 17px); -moz-transform: translate(0px, 17px);">

        <div>

             <select name="amt">

              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>

            </select>

        </div>
    </div>​
```

Comment: could you please post your code. I suggest you make a jfiddle account and post your code there this way we can all see what its all about.

Comment: This is also an issue in Firefox 19.0.2

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is to disable transform for Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .parent {
        transform: none;
    }
}
```

Also inside can be defined some css fallback for transform (e.g. left: 100px)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Mozilla issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=664707
The patch hasn't been released yet.